# Route on NestJS works locally but get 404 when requested on production

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nest

I'm having a problem using NestJS to create a new route on an existing server. I'm having difficulty finding the source of the problem because locally everything works as expected but in production the response to this specific request ends up being: `statusCode: 404` while all other routes are working fine.
I used yarn build (nest build) and pm2 to run, checked the files on the server console and everything seemed ok.

/xml/chaves works while /xml/status is getting on

production `{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot POST /arquivo/xml/status","timestamp":"2024-01-24T11:38:35.251Z","path":"/arquivo/xml/status"}`

local
`Status 200 OK`

files.controller.ts

```
 export class FilesController {
  constructor(
    private readonly documentoService: DocumentoService,
    private readonly filesService: FilesService
  ) {}


  @Post('/xml/chaves')
  @Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
  async downloadXmlsPorChaves(
  }

  @Post('/xml/status')
  @Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
  async downloadXmlsPorQuerySemZipar(
    @Body() body: DownloadDocumentosByQueryDto,
    @CurrentUser() user: ReqUser,
    @Res() res: Response
  ) {
    try {
      const { filtros } = body;
      const documentos = await this.documentoService.getXmlsPorQuery({
        empresa: user.empresa,
        filtros,
      });
  
      // Convertendo os XMLs em texto
      const xmlTextArray = documentos.map((documento) => ({
        status: documento.status,
        xml: documento.xml.toString('utf-8'),
      }));
  
      res.status(200).json(xmlTextArray);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  }
}
```

files.module.ts

`@Module({   imports: [DocumentoModule, ConfigModule, DatabaseModule],   providers: [FilesService],   exports: [FilesService],   controllers: [FilesController], }) export class FilesModule {}`
`

api.ts (request)

```
export const apiQueryXmlDownloadComStatus = async (
body: any
) => {
  return await api.post('arquivo/xml/status', body, {
    responseType:'text',
  })
}
```

Comment: are you sure its not POSTMAN or other app you are using? how are you sending the request?

Comment: yeah, I double checked it on postman and on production. i will update the post with the request.